# initialize swift class from objective c library

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization, init

Hello I am currently importing a project from objective C to swift. The objective C project uses a custom library which in one of the classes it has a function that takes a Class object, which, when the data is loaded it initializes an id obj with the class(code below). On the objective C side this works great! I am using the same library on swift with a bridge header but unfortunately my object is nil once the data is loaded. I verified the data object used to initialize the object has content. The custom swift class also requires me to implement an init(data: Data) initializer when I add a custom init(), I am new to swift any help would be great! Thank you!

Objective C:

Library:

```
-(id) buildRetObject:(Class)clss fromData(NSData*) data{
id obj = nil;
if (data != nil) {
obj = [[clss alloc] initWithData:data];
}
}
```

Custom Object, is a subclass of another custom object, not in library but on main app:

Item.m:

```
-(id)init{
    if ([super init]){
       //do something
    }

    return self
}
```

Same Item object in swift:

```
//customClass super class is abstactCustomClass which is a sub abstract class of NSObject class, init functions are in here, the abstract class
class Item: customClass { 

//variables

override init() {
   super.init()
   // do something
}

required init!(data: Data){
   //fatalError(message here)
   /*tried calling supers method 
    super.init(data:Data) gives error: fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(dictionary:)'*/
}

//methods
```

}

Comment: Can you post a more complete example?  What's the Swift class definition?

Comment: @Ssswift I updated my post please let me know if that is more helpful

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I was finally able to figure it out, objective C knows from the abstract class what the initializers are, swift doesn't. So all I need to do was implement this initializers and it works.

```
required init!(data: Data){
    super.init(data:Data)
}

override init(dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any]!){
    super.init(Dictionary:dictionary)
}
```